# Find out the no of digits in product between some prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

How many digits are  there in?
$2^{17}*3^{2}*5^{14}*7$.  help me.

Comment: Hint: $2^{17}\times 5^{14}=8\times 10^{14}$.

Comment: ok.i got it. total digits is 17.

Comment: Great, I am happy when a hint suffices.

Comment: In general, $n$ has $\lfloor \log_{10}n \rfloor+1$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

As André Nicolas has pointed out in the comments,

$$2^{17}\times 5^{14} = 2^3\times 2^{14}\times 5^{14} = 2^3\times 10^{14} = 8\times 10^{14}.$$

Therefore,

$$2^{17}\times 3^2\times 5^{14}\times 7 = 3^2\times 7\times 8\times 10^{14} = 504\times 10^{14} = 5.04\times 10^{16}.$$

So $2^{17}\times 3^2\times 5^{14}\times 7$ has $17$ digits.